# Tiles wont load with Map view but loads with fragment

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-fragments

i am trying to run this really simple app on my device (with maps API V2) and for some reason when trying to use MapView:

```
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:apiKey="(i did put the correct key)"
android:id="@+id/mvMap"/>
```

with the java file:

```
 public class MainMap extends MapActivity  {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.map_layout);
}
@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {

    return false;
}
```

the tiles will not load!!
but when I'm using a fragment:
        fragment 
android:id="@+id/map"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"  android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

with - extends FragmentActivity in java file it works perfectly fine...

what is going on???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read this **very good tutorial** on how to implement GoogleMaps in Android: **http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html**

**Without you posting any error message**, there could be **dozens of reasons** why your map is not showing.

The following are the **most common** misstakes:

- Forgot to set certain permissions
- API key not obtained correctly
- No Internet connection
- GooglePlayServices not up to date on your device